# [_UIWebViewScrollViewDelegateForwarder scrollViewWasRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I've a really strange error, and I cannot find the problem.

In my iPad APP I've a UINavigationController, a UITableViewController as master and a UIViewController containing a UIWebView as detail.

I launch the APP, the UITableViewController is shown. By segue I open the detail as usual. Then I have a back button in my detailviewcontroller that calls this method

```
[self.contentWebView setDelegate:nil];
[self.contentWebView stopLoading];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It gets poped and the master is shown again. Its

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

gets called, but then I get the following error:

```
2014-06-06 15:56:58.156 Knowledge[356:60b] -[_UIWebViewScrollViewDelegateForwarder scrollViewWasRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170429f60
2014-06-06 15:56:58.159 Knowledge[356:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIWebViewScrollViewDelegateForwarder scrollViewWasRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170429f60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x189582f50 [...] 0x196553aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

BUT, this happens only on the iPad Air... older iPads work as expected

UPDATE:
I added now the command **[self.contentWebView removeFromSuperview];** after "stopLoading" and now the error is happing right up there.

Comment: Have you printed object 0x170429f60 ?

Comment: The scrollViewWasRemoved is actually a method of UIWebView and not of _UIWebViewScrollViewDelegateForwarder, however, I don't understand why it is called on that... and only on iPadAir

Comment: I'm facing same problem did you find a solution?

Comment: Do you change your web view's scroll view's delegate? Something like: [self contentWebView].scrollView.delegate = self; ?

Comment: If I remember correctly I've rewritten this part with different components at the end. So, No, I didn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

***Please ignore this answer*** if you are not touching scroll view's (of the web view) delegate reference.

I was facing the same strange error. After some investigation, I found that it was happening because scroll view's (of the web view) delegate was altered in controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self webView].scrollView.delegate = self;
```

In some cases, scroll view invokes delegate method(s) even after your view controller is destroyed. This should be prevented by `weak` delegate reference, but for some reason scroll view calls delegate method on deallocated (zombie) object anyway. I assume this is a bug in the framework.

So here what you can do: set delegate reference to `nil` in your controller's `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self webView].scrollView.delegate = nil;
}
```

After deallocation, scroll view will be prevented from calling any method on no longer existing controller.